# Privacy of inner classes and accessibility from subtypes of the outer type

Tags: scala, private-members

I'm having difficulties with the private annotation of inner class methods and constructors. While this works as expected:

```
trait A {
  protected def lala = ()
}

trait B extends A {
  lala
}
```

The following doesn't:

```
trait A {
  class Lala protected()
}

trait B extends A {
   new Lala
}
```

Neither does this:

```
trait A {
  class Lala private[A]()
}

trait B extends A {
  new Lala
}
```

The only way around is something like this:

```
object Screwed {
  trait A {
    class Lala private[Screwed]()
  }

  trait B extends A {
    new Lala
  }
}
```

Does Scala really fail here to provide a clear mechanism, or am I missing something? My guess would have been that it should be `private[this.type]` but scalac doesn't want to swallow that at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well,

```
trait A {
  class Lala protected()
  new Lala
}
```

doesn't compile either. The error message seems pretty reasonable:

```
 error: constructor Lala in class Lala cannot be accessed in trait A
 Access to protected constructor Lala not permitted because
 enclosing class trait A in object $iw is not a subclass of
 class Lala in trait A where target is defined
```

Protected access means you can only access that constructor from that class or sub-classes. You're trying to call it from the enclosing trait. One thing you can do is this:

```
trait B extends A {
  class Gaga extends Lala
  new Gaga
}
```

I wouldn't expect your third example to compile, for similar reasons.

Also note the difference between a protected constructor and a `protected class`. So for example:

```
trait A {
  protected class P
  class U  // unprotected
}

class B extends A {
  new P  // OK
  new U  // OK
}

val b = new B
new b.P  // error
new b.U  // OK
```

Comment: Indeed the `protected class` is the solution that works for me

Answer (score 1):

This also works with the desired visibility (`Lala` can only be instantiated from `A` or subtypes of `A`).

```
trait A {
   class Lala private[A]()
   protected def newLala = new Lala
}

trait B extends A {
   newLala
}
```

I wonder what is the purpose of something like `protected[A]` if it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

the protected one should work for sure, what error do you get? for the private ones, the scope you define controls their visibility (so in a trait A, if you give visibility of A, it is obviously not visible in B). In the last example, you have given the scope as Screwed so anything inside Screwed would be able to see the private class. btw, I prefer to write the access modifiers as the first thing in a code line to facilitate easier reading

what version of scala are you using and what do you mean by "does not work" ?

HTH!

Comment: `error: constructor Lala in class Lala cannot be accessed in trait B`. As Luigi points out, `protected` refers to the scope of `Lala` and not `A`, and there doesn't seem to be any possible scope for visibility in __A or subtype of A__. I had expected that I would get this from `private[A]` or at least `protected[A]`.

Comment: @Sciss maybe you need a `protected class`? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Luigi, I thought returning an instance of a `protected` inner class is produces a problem with `Lala` 'escaping' its context, but you are right, this works!